# How to remove padding from a li element?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a Popular post widget whose css is modified by me at the blogger-template. When I save the template, My website shows a `.7em padding` on top and bottom of each `li` element of the Popular Post Widget,(Seen by Inspect Element). But in the css I have not given any. Even the whole template does not contain any padding of .7em. I have forcefully removed the gaping by `negative margin` in the `li` tag. But that makes a little problem in the hover effect. and as there is no provision of negative padding, what to do in such situation. Any idea?

Comment: This is probably set by the browser itself (default user stylesheet). You may be able to overwrite it with `li { padding: 0; }`, but you'll probably want to be specific (adding the list's ID or class). You may also need to remove `list-style` on the parent `ul`. Kind of hard to tell without seeing your actual code, though.

Comment: If there are multiple CSS files then `li { padding: 0 !important; }` could be a suitable workaround.

Comment: Ya. Solved. I have totally forgotten that I can over-write the padding with 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the obvious:

```
li { 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Ha ha. I was thinking in a tough way! To make the margin negative instead of over-writing its padding. But still do not understand from where the padding was coming. However. Thanks..